# VBScript Execute Method Does Not Declare Variables

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, execute

I was looking into dynamic "includes" methods and came down to a solution which uses VBScript's Execute function. This works perfectly for me but I noticed that Execute executes the code but this code cannot declare anything like a variable or function:

```
Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFSO.FileExists(Server.MapPath(strFile)) Then
  Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath(strFile), 1)
  strSource = objFile.ReadAll

  // Filter out comment- and ASP tags cos they return errors
  strSource = Replace(strSource, Chr(60)&Chr(37), "")
  strSource = Replace(strSource, Chr(37)&Chr(62), "")
  objRegExp.Pattern = "^[ \t]*(//¦\')[\s\S]*?$"
  strSource = objRegExp.Replace(strSource, "")

  // Execute the code
  On Error Resume Next
  Execute strSource 'etc........
end if
```

Why? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you want to use [`ExecuteGlobal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/342311f1%28VS.85%29.aspx) instead.  I imagine that your dynamic includes file loader is in a subroutine, so when you use `Execute`, the new variables are scoped within that subroutine.  `ExecuteGlobal` will ensure that the new variables are available globally.